# Batch to disable autofill and ask to save passwords in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, batch, command-line-arguments

I can't manage to disable "Autofill" and "Ask to save password" in Chrome

I've got something from another web-page, but it didn't work. This I what I got from the web-page:

```
REM Disable password saving
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome" /v PasswordManagerEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0

REM Disable autofillform
reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome" /v AutoFillEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

This is my batch so far.

Can anybody help?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. It's a kind of work'a'round

First I disabled autofill and autosave password in chrome, and after that I saved the preference-file.

Now I just have to copy the preference-file to another chrome-installation.